# Using this.selectedIndex inside an array in an 'onchange' with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, onchange

So basically I'm using one function to generate a second function using html tags and I can't get the selectedIndex of the function to be allowed to be used as a parameter in the array. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

```
var albums = [{...},{...},..];
function generateSearchFunction(albums){
    var html = "<div class='titles'> List of the search results: </div>";//
    html += "<form><select size='10' id='searchList' onchange='parent.getDetailList(albums[this.selectedIndex].albumIndex,albums[this.selectedIndex].trackIndex)'>";
    for(var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++){
    html += "<option>";
    html += albums[i].tracks;
    html += "</option>";
    }
    html += "</select></form>";
    }
}

getDetailList(albumIndex,trackIndex){...}
```

Comment: Where is `albumResults` defined? Also, you should consider adding the `onchange` event and method call after adding your dynamic HTML to the DOM. Would be cleaner and easier to debug the JS over concatenating it into the HTML.

Comment: If I call the onchange event after the generated HTML, then how would I use this.selectedIndex? also edited, the albumResults should be just albums in length.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5HGU3/)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
//Your array
var albums = [
    {
        tracks: '1: Song 1',
        trackIndex:1
    },{
        tracks: '2: Song 2',
        trackIndex:2
    },{
        tracks: '3: Song 3',
        trackIndex:3
    }
];

//Generate the HTML
function generateSearchFunction(albums){
    //Strings in JS are immutable so use an array for better performance. 
    var html = ["<div class='titles'> List of the search results: </div><form><select size='10' id='searchList' >"];
    for(var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++){
        html.push(
            "<option data-trackindex='"
            ,albums[i].trackIndex
            ,"'>"
            ,albums[i].tracks
            ,"</option>"
        );
    }
    html.push("</select></form>");
    return html.join("");
}

//Your event listener
function getDetailList(e){
    var selIndex = this.selectedIndex; 
    alert(selIndex); 
    alert(this.children[selIndex].getAttribute('data-trackindex')); 
}

//Add the JS to the DOM
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = generateSearchFunction(albums);

//Get a reference to the searchList
var el = document.getElementById("searchList"); 

//Add event listeners (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener('change', getDetailList, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent)  {
    el.attachEvent('onchange', getDetailList);
}
```